# Нужен плагин или скрипт для мягкого скролла,чтобы корректно работала функция jquery

Tags: jquery, плагин

Привет всем.ПОсоветуйте плагин какой-нибудь или скрипт, чтобы смягчить скролл страницы во всех браузерах. Пробовал `plugins-scroll`, но есть проблема.
У меня в коде есть функция, которая работает с одним из элементов(делает легкий паралакс-при скролле постепенно опускает элемент), так вот с `plugins-scroll` получается, что в `Mozilla` все работает нормально, а в `IE`, `Chrome` и `Opera` элемент паралаксирует, но делает это не плавно, а дергается, рывками, как будто у него судорога предсмертная!
Вот код используемой функции, если он необходим для ответа.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
var st = $(this).scrollTop(); 
$(".logos").css({ 
"transform" : "translate(0%," + st/3 + "%" 
}); 
});
```

Может полифилл есть какой(как мне посоветовали-))...

Comment: Дело не в самом скролле страницы. Мне подходит по идее любой плагин(сейчас вставил nicescroll.js и работает). Вопрос в том, чтобы работал смягчал так, чтобы судорог элемента не было.

Comment: так если работает, тогда в чем вопрос?)

Comment: вопрос в том, что если привязать плагин (из вышеперечисленных), то они смягчают скролл но элемент при обработке вышеуказанной функции дергается как парализованный!

Comment: ПОлагаю ты уже прочитал в другой трактовке в чем вопрос..

Comment: как я понял, скролл работает, страница плавно прокручивается, но при прокрутке отдельные элементы(элемент) начинают дергаться на странице?

Comment: Да, именно.Выше приведена функция, которая создает легкий паралакс(при скролле элемент медленно опускатся вниз).Во всех браузерах работает нормально а в IE он как паралитик дергается, то есть шаг очень резкий что ли, не знаю как правильнее сказать.он как по ступенькам опускается на круглом колесе.

Comment: Для корректной работы некоторых функций в IE существуют полифилы, нужно поискать нужный для того скрипта, который вы поставили

Comment: я уже думаю, может отключить его для IE(всмысле именно эту функцию), вот только не знаю как сделать эту обработку с отключением..условные комментарии тут мне кажется не подойдут, так как функция в теле файла с функциями и выносить ее в тело страницы не хотелось бы..

Comment: полифиллы это интересно, я использую один такой костыль для vh,vw, но вот как сформулировать сей вопрос в данном конкретном контексте даже не предполагаю..

Comment: я почитал про nicescroll.js. IE6+ поддерживает, поэтому странно, почему так дергается именно для IE

Comment: Я сам не понимаю..Возможно у него другой шаг скролла.МОжет знаешь тогда как отключить обработку именно этой одной функции в коде?

Comment: шаги геморные, но должны работать: можно подключить Detect.js, потом создаем объект `user`, который будет содержать информацию `Detect.js`. Далее вызываем `detect.parse()` с `navigator.userAgent` в качестве аргумента
`var user = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);` и после определяем тип браузера и версию через `console`: выводим `console.log(
  user.browser.family
  user.browser.version
  user.os.name
)`. Саму эту проверку уже можно в функцию нужную вставить, и написать условие, типа если версия такая, то функция к примеру: `return`

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ.Суть понял, буду разбираться.Думаю должно получится...

Answer (score 0):

> mCustomScrollbar
>
> Вот ссылка на документацию

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: это не решает проблему..